# C++ Сброс ядра при очистки памяти

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

есть 2 двумерного динамического массива один типа char другой типа sf::Sprite(из SFML)

при очистке массива типа char происходит сброс ядра

вот код:
World.h:

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

typedef unsigned short int _usi;

class World : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    World();
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    void generateWorld();
    ~World();

private:
    sf::Texture textureTile;

    //level one
    const _usi worldLevelOneHeight = 10;
    const _usi worldLevelOneWidth = 20;
    char** worldLevelOne;
    sf::Sprite** worldSpriteLevelOne;
};

#endif // WORLD_H
```

World.cpp:

```
#include "world.h"
#include <iostream>
World::World()
{
    textureTile.loadFromFile("media/Tiles.png");
    worldLevelOne = new char*[worldLevelOneHeight];
    worldSpriteLevelOne = new sf::Sprite*[worldLevelOneHeight];
    for(_usi h = 0; h < worldLevelOneHeight; ++h)
    {
        worldSpriteLevelOne[h] = new sf::Sprite[worldLevelOneWidth];
        worldLevelOne[h] = new char[worldLevelOneWidth];
    }
}

void World::generateWorld()
{
    worldLevelOne[0] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[1] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[2] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[3] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[4] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[5] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[6] = "====================";
    worldLevelOne[7] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[8] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[9] = "                    ";
    worldLevelOne[10] ="                    ";
    for(_usi h = 0; h < worldLevelOneHeight; ++h)
    {
        for(_usi w = 0; w < worldLevelOneWidth; ++w)
        {
            //set textures
            if(worldLevelOne[h][w] != ' ')
            {
                worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setTexture(textureTile);
                if(worldLevelOne[h][w] == '=') worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,73,73));
                else  worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(73,0,73,73));
                worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w].setPosition(w*73, h*73);
            }
        }
    }
}

void World::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    for(_usi h = 0; h < worldLevelOneHeight; ++h)
    {
        for(_usi w = 0; w < worldLevelOneWidth; ++w)
        {
            target.draw(worldSpriteLevelOne[h][w], states);
        }
    }
}

World::~World()
{
    for(_usi h = 0; h < worldLevelOneHeight; ++h)
    {
        delete[] worldLevelOne[h]; //ТУТ ОШИБКА
        delete[] worldSpriteLevelOne[h];
    }
    delete[] worldSpriteLevelOne;
    delete[] worldLevelOne;
}
```

тут создается World:

```
#include "game.h"
#include "world.h"

//Конструктор игры, присвоение данных
Game::Game(unsigned short int windowWidth, unsigned short int windowHeight, bool isFullScreen, unsigned short int fps)
{
    this->windowWidth = windowWidth;
    this->windowHeight = windowHeight;
    this->isFullScreen = isFullScreen;
    this->fps = fps;
}

//функция основнова цикла игры
void Game::open()
{
    //создание мира
    World world;
    world.generateWorld();

    //FullScreen или нет
    if(isFullScreen)
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Platformer", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
    else
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Platformer");

    window.setFramerateLimit(fps); //ставим FPS

    //цикл игры
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        while(window.pollEvent(ev))
        {
            if(ev.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(100,255,50));
        window.draw(world);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

при чем массив типа sf::Sprite очищается нормально, а char со сбросом ядра

Comment: Или используйте   контейнер C++ строк вместо указателей на С_строк или внимательно анализируйте отладчиком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно выделенные на строке `worldLevelOne[h] = new char[worldLevelOneWidth];` указатели затираются указателями на строковые литералы в `worldLevelOne[0] = "                    ";` (это вообще-то невалидная операция). Вместо `char** worldLevelOne;` используйте `std::vector` размером `worldLevelOneHeight` x `worldLevelOneWidth`

Comment: P.S. строковой литерал  имеет тип const char* а не char*

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, строковой литерал в C++ имеет тип `const char [N]`.

Comment: @eanmos, верно, я не так выразился _ имел ввиду, что присвоить можно ...

Comment: переписовать....